# Boto3, S3 check if keys exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Right now I do know how to check if a single key exists within my S3 bucket using Boto 3:

```
    res = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=record.bucket_name, Prefix='back.jpg', Delimiter='/')
    for obj in res.get('Contents', []):
        print(obj)
```

However I'm wondering if it's possible to check if multiple keys exist within a single API call. It feels a bit of a waste to do 5+ requests for that.

Comment: I would use `head_object()`

Answer (score -1):

You could either use `head_object()` to check whether a specific object exists, or retrieve the complete bucket listing using `list_objects_v2()` and then look through the returned list to check for multiple objects.

Please note that `list_objects_v2()` only returns 1000 objects at a time, so it might need several calls to retrieve a list of all objects.

Comment: The head_object() method takes about 0.6 seconds to finish. The list_objects_v2() is the way to go if I would want to call the API 5+ times. It finishes way faster. Still time will grow linearly if I use that function. I think it's strange the AWS doesn't have an API call that let's you check multiple keys. Yes, I could list all keys from a bucket, but that doesn't seem right to me. Especially when the bucket starts to grow. It will make it less future proof as I will still have to do a lot of API calls.

Comment: You can send API requests in parallel (eg via multithreading) if the total execution time is of concern to you.

Comment: That would be a wise choice indeed. Unfortunately I am using Lambda and it only works on one core (long story short). As far as I am aware these boto3 calls are blocking so using async won't help either.

Comment: Not sure if it needs a larger memory allocation, and thus multiple cores, or whether it will work on minimal settings too: [Parallel Processing in Python with AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/)